# Exporting Matlab matrix values to OpenGL

Tags: c++, matlab, opengl

I am doing a project which requires me to work with OpenGL. However, I am a complete novice at it!
Basically, what I need to do is do a bit of processing with Matlab on an image, and store the values for that image in a matrix. 
This matrix must be imported to OpenGL so that I can work with it a bit. How should I approach this?
Also I have a few questions:

1. Is OpenGL similar to Matlab in the sense that having a matrix with values I can just do something similar to `imshow()`?
2. In what format should I store the matrix values in so that they can be read by the OpenGL for display?
3. Some good resources to learn OpenGL from the very basics should help. I have tried to find them on google and they have been helpful.
4. I am running OpenGL on Microsoft Visual C++ 2008. Is there any other software I could use intead of this?

Comment: you could give a try to [OpenTK](http://www.opentk.com) their matrix and vector are quiet well implemented, if you're familiar with c#

Comment: @j-p Unfortunately, I am not familiar with C#. Also, the project requires me to work ahead with OpenGL.

Comment: OpenTK is openGL wrapper for c#, very stable and with .net facilities,

Comment: @j-p Thank you. Will try it! Isn't there any way to export matrix values (via .csv files maybe?) to OpenGL and then display the picture?

Comment: I don't know matlab, but isn't it what you searching for [this](http://abarry.org/speed-up-matlab-figures-with-opengl/)

Comment: @j-p excellent link! Will try it out!

Answer (score 0):

Answering to your 1st question.

```
image_1=imread('your filepath');
//do some process
//
save('image_1.mat')
```

then call it in your OpenGL.
Use this [Matlab Open GL](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/opengl.html) link to call OpenGl in Matlab.

Comment: I did have a look at that earlier. Trying it out right now. Much of the work that needs to be done later in the project seems to be through OpenGL. In which case, I might not be able to use Matlab later. Can I not do it just through OpenGL once the matrix is obtained from Matlab?

Comment: Yes. in that case you can write a small matlab code to pre process your image and save it to disk drive. then write a bat file that will execute that Matlab code. Call this .bat file from your Open GL so that everything will be in one place.. I am not sure if you can call Matlab files using OpenGl. hope this helps

Comment: will try :). I was trying to save the matrix I get from Matlab onto a textfile or .csv file. Then call this from the OpenGL code so that I can access the matrix.